# Track State changes in Corda

Tags: corda

I am planning to use vaultTrack method to track the changes in state object.Once I capture the events at client level am planning to store those data in offline DB or invoke another API. Will there will be any challenge in this implementation. As per my understanding RPC client library will be listening all the time for state changes and also it handles the incoming RPC calls from external parties . Will it slow down the performance. How exactly vaultTrack method working internally .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I don’t see any challenge in your implementation.

In Corda we use Apache Artemis for RPC communication. The Corda-RPC library must be included on the client side in order to connect to the server.

Internally this works like this -

At startup Artemis will be created on the RPC client(client side) and RPC server (within the corda node), client and server queues are created, and sessions are enabled/established between client and server. The Corda-RPC library contains a client proxy, which translates RPC client calls to low-level Artemis messages and sends them to the server Artemis instance. These RPC requests are stored on the server side in Artemis queues. The server side consumer retrieves these messages, approprite RPC calls are made, and an acknowledgement is sent to the client. Once the method completes, a reply is sent back to the client. The reply is wrapped in an Artemis message and sent across by server Artemis to the client Artemis. The client then consumes the reply from client Artemis queue.

The client proxy within the the Corda-RPC library abstracts the above processes. From a client perspective you should only create the proxy instance and make the RPC calls.

I would urge you to use the Reconnecting Client. You can read more about this in a [blog](https://medium.com/corda/corda-rpc-reconnecting-client-eb5d9593e480) which I have written.

**Also please read the last part in the blog which talks about how to handle reconnection/failover scenarios.**